# ブックマークレットにて、「名前をつけて保存」を呼び出す方法？

Tags: browser

まず、以下のようなブックマークレットがございます。

```
javascript:open(location.pathname+"?size=1024x1024","_blank");void(0);
```

サイトの画像を1024pixelで開き直すものなのですが、このブックマークレットをクリックした際、
新しいタブではなく、「名前をつけて保存」のダイアログを呼び出して、
開いたファイルをそのまま保存するようにすることはできますでしょうか。

勝手に、

```
javascript:open(location.pathname+"?size=1024x1024","_download");void(0);
```

のようなシンプルな記述等があるのかと思ったのですが、違うようで困っております。

お知恵拝借できましたら幸いです。

Comment: ブックマークレットを使わず単純に「画像を保存」では駄目なのでしょうか？ / 試行錯誤の末なのかもしれませんが、元の「画像を指定サイズで開き直す」の時点で正常に動作する環境が限られている気がします。 / まず何をしたいのかを先に説明してもらった方が良さそうです。

Comment: おっしゃるとおり、使用用途はかなり限られています。古い作りの素材サイトがありまして、そこから素材をDLする際にサイズのパラメータを指定してサッとDLできれば良いと思い、質問させていただきました。